# Distinction between statements, declarations, and expressions in formal grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I am learning basic grammar and parsing concepts and ran into this statement:

> Nonterminal symbols represent syntactic entities: statements, declarations, or expressions.

But the three terms (statements, declarations, expressions) were not really defined. I have plenty of programming experience so I have a fairly intuitive grasp of the terms, but I'm wondering, from a *language grammar* standpoint, what are the generally accepted definitions for each? When I searched online I found several language-specific discussions but nothing that gave a general definition of these terms that can apply across any language.

Are there such definitions out there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are informal terms. For example, in the C language:

1. Statements are things like `x = 3;`.
2. Declarations are things like `int x;`.
3. Expressions are things like `x * y`.

So declarations are a particular type of statements, and expressions appear in statements.

A better formulation of the statement you quoted would be:

> Nonterminal symbols represent syntactic entities such as statements, declarations, or expressions.

Comment: Ah, then that explains why I couldn't find anything formally defining them. I can deal with their standard informal meanings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Purely from a *language grammar* standpoint: There is no distinction among these terms.  The distinction comes from how individual fragments of the grammar are used in the translator based on the grammar.  In the absence of translation, it's all just syntax.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have qualified it so strictly then. ;)  But your point is well taken, thanks for clarifying.